# HTML 5 Server-Sent Events in WCF

Tags: wcf, events, rest, html

Has anybody been able to implement HTML 5 server-sent events using WCF REST? I have attempted to do it by creating a rest service that returns a Stream and this works if I use a "hard coded" event stream (i.e. I just create a string with the event text in, turn it into a MemoryStream that is then returned by the service operation). I can then see the events happening in my test page in Chrome. However, when I try to add events to the stream asynchronously, it fails because the stream is already closed. I think I need a way of keeping the stream open permanently.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

p.s. I can't use a duplex WCF binding for this because the HTML 5 specifies non-SOAP clients (obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a WCF binding for this called NetHttpBinding:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nethttpbinding.aspx

Alternatively the same thing can be achieved using SignalR, which is part of ASP.Net

http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to implement your own Binding in this case. There's no built-in Binding for comet (server-push).